# Sum of latest transactions SQL query needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having difficulty coming up with a query. I am fairly new with SQL, so the solution will likely seem obvious to a veteran but I have honestly tried and can't think anymore. I have a table called Transactions, which has the relevant columns: ID (int), CustomerID (int), Amount (int), and TransactionDate (date). I want the sum of all customers' latest transactions. TransactionDate can be entered/changed manually, so ID will only be used as a secondary sort parameter if there are multiple transactions on that latest date.

What I had before becoming frustrated:

```
SUM (
    SELECT  TOP 1 Amount
    FROM    Transactions
    GROUP   BY CustomerID
    ORDER   BY TransactionDate DESC, ID DESC
)
```

I know why it is wrong and that it's probably not even close to what I need, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Give your question a **specific** not *generic* title, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT Amount,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID
                      ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC, ID DESC) AS RN
  FROM Transactions
)
SELECT SUM(Amount)
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT id, CustomerID, Amount
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id, CustomerID, Amount
        ,rank() over(Partition BY CustomerID ORDER BY TransactionDate,id DESC ) AS Rank 
    from Transactions
) AS a
WHERE a.Rank<=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME, @ToDate DATETIME
SELECT @FromDate = '1/1/2009', @ToDate = '1/1/2010'

SELECT SUM(Amount)
FROM    Transactions
WHERE TransactionDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
GROUP   BY CustomerID
ORDER   BY TransactionDate DESC, ID DESC
```

This might help you